# Prefixes when using docker-compose run -rm

Tags: bash, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, development-environment

I am working on a PHP project using Laravel and I have several utilities in my `docker-compose`:

```
  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ["npm"]
```

With this I have to prefix each command with `docker-compose run -rm` such as:

```
docker-compose run -rm npm update
```

Is there a way to simply have an environment that set some aliases (`npm`, `grunt`, `composer`, `mysql`...) when I am in that project in VSCode?

Comment: What sort of aliases are you looking for? If those binaries are installed, you don't need any aliases to run them.

Comment: Those libraries are not installed :) When I am working in this project using for instance VsCode, I would like to use `docker-compose run -rm` as prefix when I call `npm`.

Comment: You mean like `alias npm='docker-compose run -rm npm'`? Making it work that way only in a specific drectory is a minor tweak, though I would switch to a shell function (actually basically always; aliases suck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [task in VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

> Lots of tools exist to automate tasks like linting, building, packaging, testing, or deploying software systems. Examples include the TypeScript Compiler, linters like ESLint and TSLint as well as build systems like Make, Ant, Gulp, Jake, Rake, and MSBuild.

[image]

[VScode Task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

it should be placed inside `.vscode`

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── .vscode
    └── tasks.json
```

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "npm",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker-compose run ${input:npm}",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "composer",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker-compose run ${input:compose}",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "npm",
            "description": "npm argument:",
            "default": "npm",
            "type": "promptString"
        },
        {
            "id": "compose",
            "description": "compose argument:",
            "default": "composer",
            "type": "promptString"
        }

    ]
}
```

Now All set, all you need to press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and both task will be listed, select and execute the task.

[image]